# how do you determine the IP address of the top level gateway if there are subnetworks?

Tags: dhcp, subnet

I posted this somewhere else, but someone suggested I ask it here.

I live in a community that "provides" internet service to homeowners. So, in essence, the community has a fixed IP address, then builds out a sub-network by having a giant router with appropriate masking, then the router in each home does the same. In essence, the whole community shares an IP address, but the community service puts in a router from the ISP to all homes, and each home's router sees a different gateway because of this nesting of routers.

So, when I look at my router, the address of my devices are all like 169.128.50.12. but when I look at my gateway, it has an address like 169.0.0.1 Or some such).

Today I got an alert from Google (which I am trying validate as authentic, because it led me through a process and wanted me to change my password - which could be a scam -  that someone in my physical area was blocked from logging in, even though they knew my account name and password. I am trying to figure out if it is authentic, but it may simply be that the whole community has an IP address to the ISP of, say, 12.62.126.73 (the sort of address reported in the alert), and my own login triggered the alert.

In a nested internet architecture such as that, how can one tell what the IP address of the community's gateway is? I can't see it on my router, because all it knows (via the mask and DHCP assignment) is that it's location on the community internet is 169.0.0.1. But that is its sub-net address.

Is there a clever way to use ping or traceroute to figure out the whole community's IP address is? I suspect one of my own devices tried to log in, but Google thought some unknown IP address was trying to infiltrate, because what it saw was the community IP address.

Answer (score 2):

What I always use is this
https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip+address
Literally it is the first answer

Or if you were a bash type like myself.

In a file say checkipaddress.sh, easily made with

```
vi checkipaddress.sh
```

Insert this

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -q -O - checkip.dyndns.org  | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

Change permissions

```
chmod +x checkipaddress.sh
```

Run from place

```
./checkipaddress.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `traceroute` to a public address will give you the internal addresses of every router in your community network.

The external router must perform a source address translation, so the address, which identifies you on the Internet is actually the router's address. Do a Google search for "my IP" and visit a couple of answers. If they give you always the same result, it means you will always appear with this address.

**Edit:** I assume the routers are professional devices, so they do not support [IGDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol), [NAT-PMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_Port_Mapping_Protocol) and similar hacks.

Comment: Let me be more specific.  I am in Mexico.  When I do a traceroute, I see the usual entry as the first one (129.168.50.1 with 1 ms to respond), then the next is  192.168.1.254 (with 1-2 ms to respond), then the third is clearly inside the phone network (ipds1-bcs-ca..... type of entry, 3 ms to respond), so within the ISP network.  When I set my browser to the second entry (192.168.1.254) I get a router whose username is filled in as TELMEX already.  So, would this be how an ISP would configure over fiber - having a router-like device that mates with the ISP internal packet network?

Comment: Maybe they configure the router through the web interface you found. However the address you are interested in is the external address of `192.168.1.254`. To find it you need a web page that will display "your" IP address. They also may map your internal address to several external addresses according to the destination IP, so if you check several "what's my ip" pages, you'll find what addresses are they using.

Answer (score 0):

### Google account security

Do **not** click any links in email. Go directly to your account, or accounts you manage in G Suite, by entering it in the address bar as usual. Look at the security checklist, a helpful shortcut is https://security.google.com/.

Take action on any security events. Add auth factors with hardware tokens or a TOTP app. 2FA is possibly the best thing you can do for account security, quite a bit more difficult than a static password.

Google's device list is particularly helpful in tracking down what is logged in and what is not. If necessary, there is a "Don't recognize a device?" link that jumps right into password reset and forced log off.

---

### NAT

NAT44 to share an IPv4 address would mean many users come from the same address to any Internet destination. If you had access to the edge router, you could query it directly for that IP on its interface. Or, one of the many "what is my IP" APIs provide an quick answer because they already are external.

Presumably Google sees a lot of users behind NATs logging in.  By itself say 100 devices owned by 50 accounts appearing from one IPv4 address is not necessarily a problem. But do the security checkup and review devices.

NATs are problematic for less sophisticated security controls. A service banning your IPv4 address would block your entire community. Also, the connection tracking required for NATs is tricky to scale well and may cause performance issues.

So consider advocating for an IPv6 implementation so you can have personal subnets without NAT. traceroute is easier to read when you recognize the prefix of the first few hops.

Comment: It looks like a legitimate warning from Google, but how does Google pop up a screen on my PC to warn me?  I want to see that again as it gave the IP address where the suspicious device was located...but, when I go to the link you gave and look into it, there is very little information other than the time and location.  (I suspect it was me, but knowing the network topology now I would know for sure ifI had the IP they suspected)

Comment: It could be authentic, but beware phishing. Personally, I only expect Google account security notifications on Android, or in a browser after I initiated account log in.  IP address tells you nothing if it is shared so widely.  Add 2FA, reset password, and check physical security of your devices if you are concerned.

Comment: So, if I am logged into Google on Chrome, and a message pops up, that is a (at least possibly) legitimate communication (no email - just a browser window appearing)?

Comment: Difficult to say its authenticity, unless maybe you provided a screenshot. Personally I would not be too concerned if my user's security checkups passed, and devices stayed on familiar IPs.  How to use Google account security effectively might also be on topic for Security and  Web Applications  Stack Exchanges.